# Unsupported ISO 3166 country ES?

Tags: java, android, iso-3166

My Android app from what I've tested works fine with UK and US locales, but when I change the locale to ES I receive the following error:

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported ISO 3166 country: es

I've checked ISO 3166 and es is definitely a valid country code. I've tried changing it to upper case, no difference.

Here's the offending code:

```
Currency myCurrency;
myCurrency = Currency.getInstance(Locale.getDefault());
```

Any ideas?

Comment: One thing you could try is `getAvailableLocales()` and try to see if `es` is an installed locale.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Locale` names are formed by a *language code* (lowercase), and an **optional** *country code*. You should set the default locale to `es-Es`. For instance, `Locale.US` is actually `en-US`.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try these suggestions once I got my eclipse install back up and running...

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
Currency.getInstance(new Locale("es", "ES"));
```